# PhpStorm continuation indent unexpected behavior

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I'm attempting to format my code in PhpStorm, but for multiline return statements, the code is being double-tabbed (8 spaces) even though I've specified 4 spaces in the code style options.

Here's how it looks
[image: Here's how it looks]

Here's how it should look
[image]

Here's my PhpStorm codestyle

```
<code_scheme name="OneUp_PHP_CodeStyle">
  <PHPCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="ALIGN_KEY_VALUE_PAIRS" value="true" />
    <option name="COMMA_AFTER_LAST_ARRAY_ELEMENT" value="true" />
    <option name="LOWER_CASE_BOOLEAN_CONST" value="true" />
    <option name="LOWER_CASE_NULL_CONST" value="true" />
    <option name="BLANK_LINE_BEFORE_RETURN_STATEMENT" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_CLASS_CONSTANTS" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_COLON_IN_RETURN_TYPE" value="true" />
    <option name="NAMESPACE_BRACE_STYLE" value="2" />
  </PHPCodeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="PHP">
    <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_CONTROL_STATEMENT_IN_ONE_LINE" value="false" />
    <option name="SPECIAL_ELSE_IF_TREATMENT" value="true" />
    <option name="IF_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="DOWHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="WHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="FOR_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

[image]

Here is the code in question

```
// Evaluate that the checkout contains all required coupon items.
collect($coupon->checkout_contains)->reduce(function ($carry, $requiredItem) use ($request) {
    // Iterate over checkout items for each required item, and make sure
    // that at least one checkout item satisfies each required item.
    return $carry && collect($request->items)->reduce(function ($carry, $checkoutItem) use ($requiredItem) {
        return $carry || (
            $requiredItem->product_id == $checkoutItem->product_id &&
            $requiredItem->quantity <= $checkoutItem->quantity &&
            $requiredItem->type == $checkoutItem->type
        );
    }, false);
}, true);
```

I'm using PhpStorm 2017.2.1 on Windows 10

---

**JetBrains Issue Tracker ticket:** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37751

Comment: Please provide your indentation settings for PHP (screenshots). Also -- some code sample as a file (so I can open it in my IDE here and see how it behaves).

Comment: I've attached the screenshot and the code, thanks!

Comment: I've checked some options that I though may affect this.. but got the same result. I say: submit a ticket to JetBrains Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI -- existing formatting rules may not treat such case properly (e.g. it may be related to the fact that you have `&&` logic in you return + usage of closure etc.)

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, I've updated this post with a link to the issue. If you could say that you've been able to reproduce this issue, it would probably help speed things along quicker!

Comment: I've just placed your code into an empty method of an empty class (and no Laravel framework code around). Confirming is not really required -- support team should confirm it before they accept the ticket; if they unable to reproduce it -- they will ask for additional info etc.